# undefined local variable or method `email' for Contact:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, mail-form, sendgrid-rails

I would like to use ruby **mail_form** and Heroku Sendgrid to allow users to send me an email. I have set up the following Contact class in **apps/models/contact.rb**

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base

attribute name,    :validate => true
attribute email,   :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i  
attribute message, :validate => true
attribute nickname,:captcha  => true

 def headers 
 {
   :subject => "Contact Form",
   :to      => "example@email.com",
   :from    => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
 } 
 end
end
```

However, when I visit the page where I have set up my form, I receive the following error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `email' for Contact:Class
```

Commenting out the email attribute defined in my Contact class produces similar errors in subsequent attributes **message:** and **nickname:**

Below is my Contacts controller, **contacts_controller.rb**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

 def new
   @contact = Contact.new
 end

 def create
   @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
   @contact.request = request
   if @contact.deliver
     flash.now[:error] = nil
   else
     flash.now[:error] = "Oops! There was an error."
     render :new
   end
 end

end
```

and my form, **new.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Contact") %>
<h1>Contact</h1>
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :name, required: true %>

<br>

<%= f.label :email %><br>
<%= f.text_field :email, required: true %>

<br>

<%= f.label :message %><br>
<%= f.text_area :message, as: :text %>

<div class="hidden">
<%= f.label :nickname %><br>
<%= f.text_field :nickname, hint: "Leave this field blank." %>  
</div>

<%= f.submit "Send Message", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
<ul class="pager">
<li><a href="<%= blog_path %>">Previous</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You omitted double quotes in the `from` option.

```
 def headers 
 {
   :subject => "Contact Form",
   :to      => "example@email.com",
   :from    => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
 } 
 end
```